# Slider functions don't have enough time on fast clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a simple slider using JQuery. It uses the following functions to work:

```
function moveleft(){
if (current < $length - 1){
    $tape.animate({"margin-left":"-=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
        current++;
        })
}else if(current == $length - 1){
    $tape.css("margin-left", 0);
    current = 0;
    $tape.animate({"margin-left":"-=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
        current++;  
    })
}
};

function moveright(){
if (current == 0){
    $tape.css("margin-left", -$last);
    current = $length - 1;
    $tape.animate({"margin-left":"+=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
        current--;  
    })
}else if (current > 0){
    $tape.animate({"margin-left":"+=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
        current--;
        })
}
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gdgk9wsf/

It works, but the trouble is that when user clicks buttons too fast, it probably doesn't have enough time to calculate the values. So, everything just goes far left or right. Is there anything I can add to fix it?

Comment: `.off()` the click event when arrows are clicked and `.on()` them once animation is over..Like http://jsfiddle.net/gdgk9wsf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the functions in an is animated check, like so...
This will make sure the animation finished before it can be clicked again, and do anything.

```
function moveleft(){
    if( $(tape).is(':animated') ) {return}
    else{
    if (current < $length - 1){
        $tape.animate({"margin-left":"-=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
            current++;
            })
    }else if(current == $length - 1){
        $tape.css("margin-left", 0);
        current = 0;
        $tape.animate({"margin-left":"-=" + $width}, $speed, function(){
            current++;  
        })
    }
    }

    };
```